# Toggle modal when changing text prop dynamically

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, modal-dialog

In the parent you can see the buttons when clicked change the message text

```js
<template>
..
  <button @click="msg_modal = 'hightasd'">first</button>
  <button @click="msg_modal = 'brord'">another</button>

  <!-- Msg Modal -->
  <DashboardUsedMsgModal where="bottom-left" :msg="msg_modal" :show="false" />
..
</template>

<script>
let msg_modal = ref('');
</script>
```

In the child component (Message Modal)

```js
<template>
    <Transition name="fade">
        <div v-if="showMsg"
            class="fixed min-w-[150px] h-max p-2 bg-[var(--back-dash)] flex justify-center items-center z-[20000]"
            :class="whereMod, parentStyle">
            <span class="text-white">{{ msg }}</span>
        </div>
    </Transition>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    msg: String,
    show: Boolean,
    where: String, // bottom, up, right, left, bottom-left, bottom-right, up-left, up-right (where in the page to display)
    parentStyle: String,
})
let { msg, parentStyle, show, where } = toRefs(props);

let whereMod = ref(null);
let showMsg = ref(show.value);

watch(msg.value, (newVal) => {
    // console.log(newVal);
    showMsg.value = true;
    setTimeout(() => showMsg.value = false, 1500);
}, {
    immediate: true,
    deep: true,
})
</script>
```

**What I want to do is when `msg` changes, dynamically show Message Modal and after some seconds hide it again**

The problem is that `watch` works the first time only and doesn't work again. I want to watch the prop (msg) and on change show the modal, then after 1500ms hide it. How can I fix it?

Comment: `msg.value` is an invalid watch source.  You should see a warning from Vue in your console about this... It should be the ref itself, e.g. `watch(msg, (newValue => { ... })`

Comment: i cannot understand you, what is invalid... i use watch on prop var that when change i do something, but the problem that this is not work, and no wrong with syntax as you can see or something else, please make your response is clear to understand you

Comment: I will try and make it simpler.  `watch(msg.value)`  = WRONG.   `watch(msg)` = CORRECT.  Try it

Comment: In case it helps, my answer below has a link to working code in a Vue Playground.  I would've given it in a comment but the link is too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue should have a warning for you in the console

> Invalid watch source:   A watch source can only be a getter/effect function, a ref, a reactive object, or an array of these types.

To correctly use `watch`, you should watch the ref `msg` and **not** the inner value `msg.value`

```
watch(msg, () => { // changed from msg.value
    showMsg.value = true;
    setTimeout(() => showMsg.value = false, 1500);
}, {
    immediate: true,
    deep: true,
})
```

[Vue Playground simplified example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: nice work,  i get another solve for this problem, and now you solved this with this code also, So am solved this problem two times with at the same time... nice one